# Implicit conversion to float using avr-gcc: uint8_t vs. uint16_t

Tags: c++, arduino, floating-point, type-conversion, avr-gcc

I have a question regarding the implicit conversion of `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` using the Arduino IDE 1.8.2 (gcc 4.9.2.). The hardware is a standard Arduino (ATMega328p).

I wrote a piece of code using `uint8_t` and decided afterwards to switch to `uint16_t`. (Should have seen that coming...)

However, they seem to behave slightly different for implicit conversions, what caused errors in the program.

A minimum working example is the following:

```
void setup()
{
  uint8_t x = 15;
  uint8_t y = 5;
  float myF = y-x;

  Serial.begin(74880);
  Serial.println(myF);
}
```

This will print -10.00 on my serial console.
That's nice and what I expected.

However, if I change `x` (or `x` and `y`) to `uint16_t` the result will be 65526.00!
If I change `myF` from float to int I get -10 again. (I never change any of the values)

As I store the result in a signed data type, I assume the compiler realises the possibility of negative values and "handles the situation correctly" (preserves the sign, as it does in the int case) or prints a warning in case it isn't happy about mismatching data types. However, even with the warning level set to "all" it never showed a warning. So I assume the compiler knows how to handle the situation without losing a sign/data.

Also since it works with int as target data type, it is surprising to me that it doesn't work with bigger float.

I have tested the situation on my x86 system - gcc 4.7.3 preserves the sign. However, in the 8-bit microcontroller world of AVR different rules/conditions might apply. (?)

So what is going on there? Maybe someone with more compiler knowledge can help out here..
(I know I could have avoided this situation by explicitly casting, but therefore I would have had to be aware of this pitfall.
So I would like to know what exactly causes it, as it really was a surprise when switching from `uint8_t` to `uint16_t`..)

I've read that according to the [integer conversion rules](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) "integer types smaller than int are promoted to int when an operation is performed on them". I assume avr-gcc follows integer promotions. (?) So I understand the actual calculation typically runs on an int anyway and is then converted to the target data type (float in this case). Is the problem here that the `uint16_t` is of equal, but not smaller size than the 16 bit int of AVR and therefore the `uint16_t` cannot be promoted? If so, why does it work with an int as the target type?

And why does it work with an int as target variable, but not with a 4-byte float?
And why doesn't it warn?

Comment: If the `int` is 16-bit then the `uint16_t` is not "smaller". Both operands are the same type, so the subtraction is done with `unsigned` and the value wraps in a well defined way.

Comment: The calculation has nothing to do with `float`, and the compiler does not "realise" anything". The result is assigned to `float` *afterwards*. You would have to cast one operand to `float` *before* the calculation to make `float` a consideration.

Comment: (yes I know 1 year and 7 months later) But what's funny is that the 'expected' result of -10 for uint8_t is not the one I expect. I would say it should be 246. And 65526 is expected. And '-10 again' is also the expected result. As you never use x and y elsewhere, maybe it has been optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is going on there?

#### Integer promotions

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type ..., the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.
> C11 §6.3.1.1 2

With the below, `y-x` promotes each `x,y` to `int` and computes 5-15 which is `int -10` and assigns that values to `mF`.

```
  uint8_t x = 15;
  uint8_t y = 5;
  float myF = y-x;
```

With the below, `y-x` promotes each `x,y` to `unsigned` and computes 5u-15u which is `unsigned  65526u` and assigns that values to `mF`.

```
  uint16_t x = 15;
  uint16_t y = 5;
  float myF = y-x;
```

Why `unsigned` and not `int`?  A `uint16_t` does not meet the "if an `int` can represent all values of the original type" condition on a 16-bit `int` platform when promoting a `uint16_t`.

No mystery, just *integer promotions*   on a platform with a 16-bit `int/unsigned`

Comment: Well, that nails it. (btw: int -10 is assigned to mF.) After revisiting the integer conversion rules with your answer and @Weather 's comment in mind I now know what is going on. I thought the compiler considers that everything will end up in a float, but that was a misconception. One more thing to consider when using C... Always cast to signed / float *manually* when signed can become necessary..or test very well...

Comment: @random In _general_, casting is to be avoided as it tends to mask errors or weak code - there are often  better alternatives.  Yet at other times it is wise.  It is very code dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You are <del>using unsigned integers to go negative</del> casting these unsigned types to a float, which is <del>undefined</del> implementation-defined behaviour. Use int8_t or int16_t to handle negative values properly. The difference in behaviour where the cast to float from uint16_t compared to the cast from uint8_t is up to the implementation, so it's hard to tell exactly what's happening.

Comment: There is no *undefined behaviour* here, but the integer conversions here depend on whether the implementation's `int` type can represent all the values of a `uint16_t` or not. So at most, it is *implementation-defined behaviour*.

Comment: For simplicity I didn't mention that the data values my program runs on are always positive values. Therefore storing them in int16_t, instead of uint16_t would decrease the possible data resolution. (and going to int32_t would double the size of the data set) As mentioned explicitly casting the variables before the calculation seems to be the way to go, still it was an unexpected finding for me, as I thought the target data type was considered by the compiler and I didn't expect problems with changing the data to a wider data type. But now I know better.